# Como cerrar un Form desde otro en C#

Tags: c#

El primero es el principal, en el cual tengo un Datagrid con datos, cuando selecciono un registro se abre el segundo form con la descripción del seleccionado, y tengo la posibilidad de editar esos datos en un tercer form. Lo cual ya lo logre hacer ya que edito en el 3er form y se actualiza directamente en el primer form. pero despues de eso quiero que me mande directo al primero y cerrar el 2do.

En el 3er Form uso lo siguiente:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Hide();
//frm.Close();   //Tambien uso esto pero sigue visible
```

Se oculta el 3er pero el 2do sigue estando visible

Comment: Cuando haces `Form2 frm = new Form2();` estas creando una nueva instancia de tu form2, que es la que ocultas, no la instancia que tienes abierta. Guarda una referencia a tu form2 cuando lo crees y esa instancia es la que debes ocultar

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado, ya lo logre hacer, no se si de la manera mas optima, pero funciono como lo necesitaba.